# Rating Control Ajax can not be showing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, rating

I am using rating control which is present in ASP.NET AJAX control toolkit. I have following questions.

1. It doesn't show up anything if I drag the control unto the page
2. CSS doesn't help either
3. How do I save the rating value in  database

Thank you very much.

CSS

```
.ratingStar
{
            font-size: 0pt;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            cursor:pointer;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }


.filledRatingStar
{
  background-image: url(images/Star_filled.gif);
}


.emptyRatingStar
{
  background-image: url(images/Star_empty.gif);
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Rating ID="Rating2" runat="server" CurrentRating="1" MaxRating="6"   StarCssClass="ratingStar"
                    WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
                    FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar"
                    EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar"
                                RatingAlign="Vertical">
                            </asp:Rating>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Rating is not showing up:

1. You're missing the style for *savedRatingStar*
2. More importantly, because you've set `RatingAling="Vertical"` you **must** specify `display:block;` for *ratingStar*

Change your code as follows and it will work:

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ratingStar
    {
        font-size: 0pt;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: block;
    }

    .filledRatingStar
    {
        background-image: url(images/Star_filled.gif);
    }


    .emptyRatingStar
    {
        background-image: url(images/Star_empty.gif);
    }

    .savedRatingStar
    {
        /*change this to your image name*/
        background-image: url(images/Saved_star.gif);
    }
</style>
```

**ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:Rating ID="Rating2" runat="server" CurrentRating="1" MaxRating="6" StarCssClass="ratingStar"
    WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar"
    RatingAlign="Vertical" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitRating" />
</form>
```

### Saving the rating to the database:

The rating is available via the `CurrentRating` property of the Rating control, simply access it in code and insert it into the db (there are literally hundreds of examples on the net how to do this, I trust you'll be able to find your way from here)

```
protected void SubmitRating(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rating = Rating2.CurrentRating;
        //Submit to database...
    }
```